# Analyzing bidding sequence

Tags: bridge

My left opponent opened 1S - Right-side opponent responded 2H (I understood: 11+, 4+ card heart suit, shortness in spades) - L.O. responded 2S - R.O. responded 3D (has shortness of spades).
R.O. : 4 diamonds, (almost) game values (?)

L.O. eventually responded 3S ---

I can't analyze it properly?

Comment: a) Could you be clearer about what you are actually asking and b) could you say what bidding system was in use?

Comment: At this point in the auction, system divergences have almost eliminated themselves. Any natural system, including various strong club systems like Precision, will likely be showing very similar hands. About the only difference left is that LHO might be a point lighter, and RHO a point heavier, so just move a jack across. LHO's spade rebid shows 6 in every system, and RHO's heart response shows either 5 hearts, or 3-4 in the majors, in virtually every system.

Comment: @TimLymington: I assume they used SAYC.

Comment: So what were the actual hands?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: actually I'm not very interested in actual hands. I want to learn to understand what the bidding moves that happened to me during the game mean

Comment: Fair enough; reading your particular opponents is useful also.

Comment: I assume you made a typing error or something as opponents have just made an insufficient bid after bidding 4 Diamonds, they can't bid 3 Spades.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LHO has a hand with just too much defense for an opening 3S call. In particular, it probably has an outside Ace. Perhaps something like:

```
AQJxxxx-x-Ax-xxx
```

RHO's 2H call almost always shows 5 hears, unless a 2-over-1 must be bid first to show a limit raise in spades. This is confirmed by the diamond following bid. So RHO's hand looks something like this:

```
x-KJTxx-KJTx-Qxx
```

or this:

```
void-KJTxx-KJTxx-Qxx
```

RHO's failure to bid clubs at the second turn denies 4 of that suit (unless perhaps 4 little, but that would be amateur), and the failure to rebid hearts denies 6, so the reds are 5-5 or 5-4. The repeated failure to tolerate spades or bid clubs shows the blacks to be 1-3 or 0-3.

RHO's reluctance to spades also infers an absence of aces; this because a couple of Aces, or an Ace and a KQ combination, would be golden to LHO.

LHO might hazard a leave in 3H with two little and diamond tolerance, so I infer a likelihood of 1-2 in the reds.